# How to give the address of "bashrc" loacted in "./opt/.../etc" in VM?

Tags: virtualbox, bashrc, source

I am a newbie in Linux. I have a VM on my windows and just installed OpenFOAM10 (https://openfoam.org/download/10-ubuntu/) on my VM. Then, I needed to add "`source /opt/openfoam10/etc/bashrc`" to the `~/.bashrc` file. However, when I did this, I constantly received an error telling me that:
"`bash: /home/user/opt/openfoam10/etc/bashrc: No such file or directory`"

I was wondering how to solve this problem. Is it related to using VM? how should I refer to a file which is located in the root of a VM?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you actually added `source ./opt/openfoam10/etc/bashrc` or perhaps `source ~/opt/openfoam10/etc/bashrc` instead of the suggested `source /opt/openfoam10/etc/bashrc`

Comment: Hi steeldriver,

Thanks for your correct comment. However, after this step when I wanted to add an alias it received a  similar error again.
I added:
  source of10="source /opt/openfoam10/etc/bashrc" 

and when I enter source ~/.bashrc I again receive:
bash: of10=source /opt/openfoam10/etc/bashrc: No such file or directory.
======
Could you please help me with this one.

Comment: Please [edit] this new information into your question, taking care to use the formating tools

Comment: The `of10` that you are trying to use should be first set as a variable then called.  `of10="/opt/openfoam10/etc/bashrc"` then `source $of10` as two separate lines.